# How to acces to output data laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

I need to display vendors without repeat, but i have large bd. 
Here is my query:

```
$model = Driver::select(DB::raw('vendor, COUNT(' . $field . ') AS s'))-
>groupBy('vendor')->pluck('s', 'vendor')->toArray();
```

It displays how many drivers have each vendor and returm massive:
[image]
I'm using twig template and when i try to display this massive with this code:

```
{% for vendor in model %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ vendor}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

It's just show me numbers, but i need vendors names.
I tried to use

```
groupBy('vendor')
```

but it says amth about not enough memory, i think becouse db have 553k rows.
How to get acces to all vendor names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looping through the values instead of the keys can you try

```
{% for key, vendor in model %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ key }}: {{ vendor }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```